# android:issue in display captured image in gridview

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, camera

Good Day

I'm trying  to capture an image with camera when I press the Button,then save it in  Sqllite and then display it in gridview..
but after I capture the image it doesn't appear in the grid view :/ no error appear in logcat except nothing displayed in gridview I don't know if the problem in camera or in gridview
can anyone help?

here is my code

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Myfiles";// directory name to store captured images
    private static String mCurrentPhotoPath;  // file path to the last image captured
    View view;
    private Uri fileUri;// file url to store image
    private GridView myGridView;
    private ImageListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Images> myLists;// image list
    Images images;
    DatabaseAdapter DBadapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            view = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);


        } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (view != null)
            init();
        return view;

    }

    // initialize all the variables
    private void init() {
        DatabaseAdapter DBadapter =new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
        DBadapter.open();
        myLists = new ArrayList<Images>();
        myLists=DBadapter.getImagesList();
        adapter = new ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.img_list_view, myLists);
       // imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageListView);
        Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.camerabutton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);// create a file to save the image
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE); // start the image capture Intent
            }
        });
        myGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        myGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
/**
     * Create a file Uri for saving an image or video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {

        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }
    /**
     * returning image /
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            //return null;

        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }


        return mediaFile;


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    //file path of captured image
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    //file path of captured image
                    File f = new File(filePath);
                    String filename = f.getName();
                    cursor.close();
                    DBadapter.insertImage(images);  //insaert image to database 
                    myLists=DBadapter.getImagesList();
                    adapter = new ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.img_list_view, myLists);
                    myGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    myGridView.invalidateViews();
   break;
 }

            case 2:
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
             } break;
    }}
}
```

here is xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.labon.invoicemanger.CameraFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout --> <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Invoice"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/camerabutton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New Invoice"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/camerabutton"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/screenshot"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <!--android:drawableRight="@drawable/screen_shot"--> </RelativeLayout> </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `startActivityForResult` you use `CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE` as a request code, but in `onActivityResult` you don't have a case for `CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE (100)`.
you need to add a case for `CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE` in your switch cases or change:

```
case 1
```

with

```
 case CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE
```

**Update:**

try this:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

for more information look
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

Comment: it case exception .RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo after i change the switch cases @Neel

Comment: I think its because you use intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri) and the trying to get the uri from the intent. You need to use fileUri instead of data.getData().

Comment: If you specified MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, the image taken will be written to that path, and no data will given to onActivityResult. You can read the image from what you specified.

Comment: after i remove MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT..the Data = null in onActivityResult which is cause nullpointerExeption @OShiffer

Comment: the camera work but i still can't display captured image in gridview @OShiffer